# Symfony 2.3 - Check if form field has validation constraint

Tags: forms, validation, twig, symfony-2.3

I have an entity and several different validation groups for different forms, which are all using that entity.
I would like to display some sort of hint (like the classic * ) for fields which are required. I am aware of the solution mentioned at http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels

However, I would like to have a more sophisticated solution, because I want to have different hints based on the type of validation constraint used.
For example, I wrote a custom constraint, which checks if at least one of several fields is not empty. All these fields should have a fitting annotation.

Is there a way to do that in Symfony 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener to watch out for `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` as [described in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class).

In that listener, you can call `$event->getData()` to fetch the entity driving the form data. From there, you can use Reflection (or Annotation parser, if you're not using PHP 8 Attributes) to determine constraints and modify your form accordingly.